# How to store local variables in a Model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a model:

```
class IceCream(db.Model):
    flavor = db.Column(db.Integer, default=2)

    licks = 0

    def update_licks(self):
        self.licks += 1
```

My goal is that I have some variables that are stored in the database, and others that aren't.  However, licks keeps resetting to 0 every time I load the object.  How can I fix this so the variable doesn't reset while the server is running?

Comment: Try assigning directly to the class itself instead of the instance, because the instance gets destroyed when the view is done rendering. Basically, instead of using the instance variable `self.licks`, assign directly to the class, i.e. `IceCream.licks`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a static variable which won't be created everytime you create a new object. You did create a static variable. But, problem is you created  an instance variable when you wrote `self.licks`. So, now you have two variable, one is a static variable named licks, which is accessible via `IceCream.licks` and other one is an instance variable which is accessible via `self.licks` inside an object. So, how to fix it is modify your code as below

```
class IceCream(db.Model):
    flavor = db.Column(db.Integer, default=2)

    licks = 0

    def update_licks(self):
        IceCream.licks += 1
```

Comment: `self.licks` in itself does not create an instance variable. It's the (fused) assignment. Just `self.licks` would still access the class variable, if no instance variable shadows it.

Comment: Are you sure, just tried it and I was able to access it

Comment: Oh, got it...yeah..if assigned to a value..it creates